# Unable to get the data from web API using authentication key

Tags: python, xml

I am new to python.
I am trying to do a GET response with token key using python.
Every time new token key will change, then passed generated token key to get the response from web api.
But i am getting below error message. Could you please any one help me on this.

**Error Msg:**
!doctype html>HTTP Status 401 – Unauthorizedh1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} h2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} h3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} b {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} p {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} a.name {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}

## HTTP Status 401 – Unauthorized

**Type** Status Report

**Message** Token expired.

**Description** The request has not been applied because it lacks valid authentication credentials for the target resource.

#### Fiberlink Server

```
import requests


# API URL to generate authentication token key
apiURL_auth = "https://services.fiberlink.com/auth-apis/auth/1.0/authenticate/1008860"
token_dict = """<authRequest>
                <maaS360AdminAuth>
                    <billingID>1008860</billingID>
                    <platformID>3</platformID>
                    <appID>com.1008860.api</appID>
                    <appVersion>1.0</appVersion>
                    <appAccessKey>XXXXXXXX</appAccessKey>
                    <userName>XXXXXXXX</userName>
                    <password>XXXXXXXX</password>
                </maaS360AdminAuth>
            </authRequest>
"""
headers1 = {"Content-Type": "application/xml"}
response = requests.post(apiURL_auth, data=token_dict, headers=headers1)
auth_token = response.text
index_1 = auth_token.index("<authToken>")
index_2 = auth_token.index("</authToken>")
index_3 = auth_token.index("<errorCode>")
index_4 = auth_token.index("</errorCode>")
error_code = auth_token[index_3:index_4].replace("<errorCode>","")
token_Key = auth_token[index_1:index_2].replace("<authToken>","")
print(token_Key)


# API URL for module data
apiURL_main ="https://services.fiberlink.com/device-apis/devices/1.0/search/1008860/?deviceStatus=Active&partialDeviceName=UKC0"
header2 = {"Authorization": "MaaS token=%s" % token_Key}
response2 = requests.get(apiURL_main, headers=header2, verify=False)
print(response2.text)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!... Is the `token_Key` according to requirements? What does the `error_code` eventually contain?

Comment: yes, token key is generating by passing all authentication information.

error_code: 401 unauthorized issue